# Windows - Alert on Event Log failure

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

I need to display a local alert when Windows Event Log fails. Other than creating a script that is triggered as part of the service recovery options, is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is using Task Scheduler in Windows. You can configure a task to trigger the PowerShell script by needed event ID in order to restore/recover a service.